# Please help me to see why this program will make an error the second time it is executed

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I want to build a small system to enter consumer information, but there is a bug in the function of adding new information. The first time you can add it normally,  but the second time you add it will add a result indefinitely. As shown in the figure, there is the file information and the program.
[image: Console Output]

Do some processing first

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Create structure 
struct stu_con {
    long time;
    int num; //student ID
    char name[10];
    double money;
    struct stu_con *next;
};

struct stu_con *head;//Global variable head pointer

//Create a linked list and enter the file into the linked list
struct stu_con *create(struct stu_con *head) {
    FILE *fp;
    struct stu_con *p1, *p2, *p;
    if ((fp = fopen("d:\\fee.txt", "r+")) == NULL) {   //Open a D drive file 
        printf("Cannot open file!\n");
        exit(0);
    } else {
        printf("Successfully opened the file!\n");
        head = p1 = p2 = (struct stu_con *)malloc(sizeof(struct stu_con));
        while ((fscanf(fp, "%d%d%s%lf", &p1->time, &p1->num, p1->name, &p1->money)) != EOF) {  //getting information 
            p1 = (struct stu_con *)malloc(sizeof(struct stu_con));
            p2->next = p1;
            p2 = p1;
        }
        p1->next = NULL;
        p1 = p2 = head;
        while (p1->next != NULL) {
            p2 = p1;
            p1 = p1->next;
        }
        p2->next = NULL;

        printf("The file is entered successfully!\n");
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return head;
};

//Show the contents of the file
void show(struct stu_con *head) {
    struct stu_con *p;
    p = head;
    while (p != NULL) {
        printf("%d\t%d\t%s\t%.2lf\n", p->time, p->num, p->name, p->money);
        p = p->next;
    }
}
```

Then the problem is here

```
//Add new information 
struct stu_con *insert(struct stu_con *head, struct stu_con *bo) {
    struct stu_con *p0, *p1, *p2;

    p1 = head;
    p0 = bo;
    if (head == NULL) {
        head = p0;
        p0->next = NULL;
    } else {
        //According to the time to determine the location to join 
        while ((p0->time > p1->time) && (p1->next != NULL)) {
            p2 = p1;
            p1 = p1->next;
        }
        if (p0->time <= p1->time) {
            if (head == p1)
                head = p0;
            else
                p2->next = p0;
            p0->next = p1;
        } else {
            p1->next = p0;
            p0->next = NULL;
        }
    }   
    return head;
};
```

Finally, the main function

```
//Main function 
int main() {
    struct stu_con bo;
    head = create(head); //Create a linked list 
    show(head);
again_n:  //Build a loop 
    printf("Please enter the student consumption information record you want to add：\n");
    scanf("%d%d%s%lf", &bo.time, &bo.num, bo.name, &bo.money);
    head = insert(head, &bo);
    printf("The information is entered successfully. \n"
           "Do you want to continue to enter it?（Y/N)：");
    getchar();
    while (getchar() == 'Y')
        goto again_n;  //Loop 
    show(head); //Show results 
    return 0;
}
```

Hope someone can help me, thanks

Comment: Just out of curiosity, which tutorial teaches `goto` before `do {...} while ()` loops?

Comment: I'm sorry that I'm not familiar with the loop structure. I think it's OK to use it in this way. I need to practice more about it.

Comment: Both are taught in the same class， just I can't use that correctly;-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- your list construction is incorrect: you always allocate a new uninitialized node before attempting to read further input from the file. The last node in the list is always bogus and removing it is cumbersome in your code. You should instead read input into local variables, and only allocate a new node if successful, adding to the tail of the list, keeping a pointer to the first and the last elements of the list.
- `fscanf()` returns the number of successful conversions. You should compare `fscanf(...) == 4)` to detect conversion errors properly.
- the file should be open for read with `"r"`, `"r+"` is update mode, which is rather tricky to use and unnecessary here.
- `%s` is a risky conversion in `fscanf()`. You should specify the maximum number of characters to store into the destination array as `%9s`.
- in `main()` you insert a structure that is a local variable in `main` instead of an allocated object. This is bad style and error prone. You should write a function to allocate a new structure and insert it in the list and use that in `create` too.
- Don't use a label and a conditional `goto`, use a `for(;;)` loop and a conditional `break` statement instead.
- you should use `%ld` for `time` that has type `long` both in `printf` and `scanf`.
- instead of passing `head` and retuning the updated value, pass a pointer to `head` and return a success indicator.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Create structure
struct stu_con {
    long time;
    int num;//student ID
    char name[10];
    double money;
    struct stu_con *next;
};

// Allocate a new structure and insert it in the list
struct stu_con *insert_stu(struct stu_con **head, const struct stu_con *stu) {
    struct stu_con *new_stu = malloc(sizeof(*new_stu));
    struct stu_con **pp;
    if (new_stu) {
        *new_stu = *stu;
        /* find the insertion position in increasing order of time */
        for (pp = head; *pp && (*pp)->time <= new_stu->time; pp = &(*pp)->next)
            continue;
        new_stu->next = *pp;
        *pp = new_stu;
    }
    return new_stu;
}

// Load records from a file and insert in the list
int load_file(struct stu_con **head, const char *filename) {
    FILE *fp;

    if ((fp = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot open file %s!\n", filename);
        return 0;
    } else {
        char buf[100];
        struct stu_con stu;

        printf("Successfully opened the file %s!\n", filename);
        while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp)) {
            if (sscanf(buf, "%ld%d%9s%lf", &stu.time, &stu.num, stu.name, &stu.money) == 4)
                insert_stu(head, &stu);
            else
                printf("Invalid record: %s", buf);
        }
        printf("The file %s is entered successfully!\n", filename);
        fclose(fp);
        return 1;
    }
}

//Show the contents of the file
void show(const struct stu_con *p) {
    while (p != NULL) {
        printf("%ld\t%d\t%s\t%.2f\n", p->time, p->num, p->name, p->money);
        p = p->next;
    }
}

//Main function
int main() {
    char buf[100];
    struct stu_con stu;
    struct stu_con *head = NULL;   //Local variable head pointer, empty list

    load_file(&head, "fee.txt");  // cannot use "d:\\fee.txt" for testing
    for (;;) {
        printf("Please enter the student consumption information record you want to add:\n");
        if (!fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin))
            break;
        if (sscanf(buf, "%ld%d%9s%lf", &stu.time, &stu.num, stu.name, &stu.money) == 4) {
            if (insert_stu(&head, &stu))
                printf("The information is entered successfully.\n");
        } else {
            printf("Invalid data: %s", buf);
        }
        printf("Do you want to continue to enter it?（Y/N)：");
        if (!fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) || *buf != 'Y')
            break;
    }
    // Show the resulting list
    show(head);
    // Free the list
    while (head) {
        struct stu_con *next = head->next;
        free(head);
        head = next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```